# Filter array so all elements with key is specified are removed

Tags: php, arrays, filter, associative-array

I'm looking for a way to filter array so all elements with key is specified are removed.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
$x = array(
    'a', // pass
    'b::a', // pass
    array('a'), // pass
    array('a', 'b'), // pass
    function() { // pass

        return 'a';

    },
    'a' => 'b', // doesn't pass because key is specified
);
```

After `remove_elements_with_key_specified($x)`...

```
array(5) {
    [0]=> string(1) "a"
    [1]=> string(4) "b::a"
    [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "a" }
    [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" }
    [4]=> object(Closure)#1 (0) { }
}
```

How to do it? Would simple check that key is a string would be the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_int()` would work:

```
foreach($x as $k=>$v){
    if(!is_int($k)){
        unset($x[$k]);
    }
}
```

From docs:

```
<?php
if (is_int(23)) {
    echo "is integer\n";
} else {
    echo "is not an integer\n";
}
var_dump(is_int(23));
var_dump(is_int("23"));
var_dump(is_int(23.5));
var_dump(is_int(true));
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
is integer
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your elements have an implicit numeric key, so I guess what you wanna do here is something like:

```
foreach($x as $key => $value) {
    if(!is_numeric($key) {
         unset($x[$key]);
    }
}
```

That should work.

Comment: `is_numeric` returns true for numeric strings as well as floats, which an array key should not be.

Comment: True, however in this case, this would do the trick. But right, is_int would work better.